# How to replace the end of text to the front in column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I had a lists of columns in MySQL. I want to perform MySQL with mariaDB query, which place the last text of the particular column A, to the first text of that particular column A.

**For example**

```
Column A
Golden Street 17a
Red Street 12/a
Street Golden
Amazing 7 Street Travel 
...


Column A
17a Golden Street
12/a Red Street
Golden Street
Travel Amazing 7 Street 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SET @x = 'Red Street 12/a';
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', -1), ' ',
                     SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', 2));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', 2)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12/a Red Street                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(Note:  I am assuming 2 blanks in the column.  If that is not the case, then edit your Question to be more precise.)

If it is just the last "word" that moves to the front, then consider:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', -1), ' ',
            LEFT(@x, LENGTH(@x) -
              LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@x, ' ', -1)))) AS swap;
+------------------+
| swap             |
+------------------+
| 12/a Red Street  |
+------------------+
```

Comment: The space between the texts are in-consistent. It can be 2 to 4 words.

Comment: Is the last piece only 1 "word"?

Comment: Yes, only last one word will be move.